# tcpdump host unreachables for specific host

Tags: tcpdump, icmp

I'm trying to rule out some issues and needing to capture all ICMP messages except echo/echo reply.  However the issue I'm struggling to find a way around is I only want these involving a particular host.

The filter I've been trying is
tcpdump icmp and 'icmp[0] != 8 and icmp[0] != 0' and host x.x.x.x
However that is only giving what is the x.x.x.x or y.y.y.y hosts.  Example of what I get but wanting to only have for z.z.z.z portion

18:06:07.823692 IP x.x.x.x > y.y.y.y: ICMP host z.z.z.z unreachable, length 48

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to filter for `z.z.z.z` in the ICMP response. Let's assume the IP of the unreachable host is `z1.z2.z3.z4`, then you should replace `host x.x.x.x` in your filter with the following filter `icmp[24] == z1 and icmp[25] == z2 and icmp[26] == z3 and icmp[27] == z4`.

If you only want the ICMP destination unreachable messages, consider using `icmp[icmptype] == icmp-unreach` instead of `icmp[0] != 8 and icmp[0] != 0`.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I've just tested it and is exactly what I'm after :)